# SVM for image feature classification?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, svm

I implemented the **Spatial Pyramid Matching algorithm** designed by
**Lazebnik** in Matlab and the last step is to do the svm
classification. And at this point I totally don't understand how I
should do that in terms of what input I should provide to the `svmtrain` and
`svmclassify` functions to get the pairs of feature point coordinates of
train and test image in the end.

I have:

- coordinates of `SIFT` feature points on the train image
- coordinates of SIFT feature points on the train image
- intersection kernel matrix for train image
- intersection kernel matrix for test image.

Which of these I should use?

Answer (score 1):

A SVM classifier expects as input a set of objects (images) represented by tuples where each tuple is a set of numeric attributes. Some image features (e.g. gray level histogram) provides an image representation in the form of a vector of numerical values which is suitable to train a SVM. However, feature extraction algorithms like SIFT will output for each image a set of vectors. So the question is:

**How can we convert this set of feature vectors to a unique vector that represents the image?**

To solve this problem, you will have to use a technique that is called [bag of visual words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model_in_computer_vision).

Comment: I know about bag of visual words, Lazebnik paper is just about it. My question is how to get the spatial information for matching two images, rather than saying that they are similar. I wanted to know is the application of SVM would lead me closer to that or not, or is it in general impossible to do the exact matching between the feature point, when working with histograms/dictionaries/bow?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that number of points is different, SVM expects feature vector to be the same size for train and for test.

Answer (score 0):

> coordinates of SIFT feature points on the train image coordinates of
>   SIFT feature points on the train image

The coordinates won't help for SVM.

I would use:

1. the **number** of found SIFT feature points
2. segment the images in small rects and use the presence of a SIFT-Feature point in a
   particular rect as boolean feature value. The feature is then the rect/SIFT-feature type
   combination. for N-Rects and M-SIFt feature point types you obtain
   N*M features.

The second approach requires spatial normalization of images - same size, same rotation

P.S.: I'm not expert in ML. I've only done some experiments on cell-recognition in microscope images.